# How to use driver object in javascript globally in appium

Tags: android, ios, appium, webdriver-io

I have to test android and ios app, I'm using wdio test runner. I have wdio.config file to test the apps. Using javascript mocha to write test.
I want to use driver instance so can access url,clear() function in my test script.
I cannot use driver object. the driver instance should work for both android and ios test as well accordingly wherever it is run.

tried by installing @wdio/protocol, but that doesnt help to create driver object. Does that work only in typescript?